# C# DataContract and DataMember for dynamic JSON object

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I can easily handle standard JSON responses using `DataContractJsonSerializer` and it works just fine. Now I have to deal with an REST API that returns some properties either as object or as an array.

Example "As Object":

```
{
    "collection": {
        "type3": {
            "param5": "foo",
            "param6": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Example "As Array":

```
{
    "collection": [
        "type1": {
            "param1": "lorem",
            "param2": "ipsum"
        },
        "type2": {
            "param3": "hello",
            "param4": "world"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the property `collection` behaves a little bit strange. If only one "Type" is available, the API returns an object. If more types are available, the API returns an array of objects. Additionaly each type of object is defined by its key `type1`, `type2` or `type3`.

I am pretty stuck at the point of organizing `DataContract` and `DataMember`. I do not know how to define the `collection` property correctly.

I am stuck here:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Demo
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Response
    {
        // [DataMember(Name = "collection")]
        // public Type1[] collection { get; set; }
        // public Type2[] collection { get; set; }
        // public Type3[] collection { get; set; }

        // [DataMember(Name = "collection")]
        // public Collection collection { get; set; }

        // ???
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Collection
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "type1")]
        public Type1 type1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "type2")]
        public Type2 type2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "type3")]
        public Type3 type3 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Type1
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "param1")]
        public string param1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "param2")]
        public string param2 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Type2
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "param3")]
        public string param3 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "param4")]
        public string param4 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Type3
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "param5")]
        public string param5 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "param6")]
        public string param6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell how to handle this situation correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your "As Array" json is invalid.  Try uploading to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jsonlint.com/.  Perhaps there's an extra set of braces around the `{"typeN": {...}}` objects that you didn't include in the question?

Comment: If your JSON were valid, and you were willing to use [tag:json.net], you should be able to use the converter from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n).

Comment: Uh nice... You are right! Just checked the api again. The responses are invalid JSON. Pretty strange. Need to contact those api guys. Thanks for that good point and quick reply!